# get identity when adding via entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, primary-key, identity-column

I'm using entity framework to insert a new record into my templates database. I would like to know what the identity of the inserted record is after the insert is done.

my code for inserting the record...

```
WEBSITE_ORDER_LINE_TEMPLATES newTemplate = new WEBSITE_ORDER_LINE_TEMPLATES();
newTemplate.customerNo = Customer.CustomerNo;
newTemplate.templateName = txtSaveTemplate.Text.Trim();
dpot.WEBSITE_ORDER_LINE_TEMPLATES.Add(newTemplate);
```

i want to know what the templateId is... in sql, this field is set as primary key and IsIdentity=Yes.

is there a quick way to get this value without searching the database where customer and templatename match? I need to know the ID because after this part, i want to enter template line information and there's a foreign key on that table on the templateId in this table.

Comment: Just inspect the relevent property after the insert (e.g. `newTemplate.templateId`), the property should have been updated to reflect the id generated by the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `SaveChanges()` method. EF updates the `newTemplate.templateId` with SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() after the INSERT.